# Windows 7 bluescreen and no display

Tags: windows-7

Bluescreen occured three times. Now there is no display, mother board and hard disk still working.

Running :  **Windows 7, ddr2 1gb ram**.

Comment: Asking from mobile. Pc still not working.

Answer (score 1):

THere are lots of issues can happened. 
You should diagnose by yourself.
Try to remove and clean from dust all components.
IF your pc has some bios signals, count them(e.g. 2 short 1 long) and then google for it depending on your bios version. In general you have to provide more details

Comment: If I might add, you should also check the Event Viewer (evntwr.msc) for any critical errors in the system log when you get BSOD crashes.